# Explanation about how to handle Unicode char with write function

Tags: c, unicode

I'm sure that the title seems to be a clone from other question. But after search on the web, I haven't found something which can answer to my question.

Sorry for my English, I'm French. I'll try to write something understandable.

For a project for my school, I must write some functions present in the glibc library. There are plenty of functions, et and there is one : putchar.

Putchar, in its "basic" implementation is very easy to write, but they ask - as a bonus -, to handle Unicode char.

So, I search to know how Unicode works (I'm a beginner), and I found how it works, kind of. I know that Unicode char are coded one 2 or more bytes, and I know also that the beginning of these bytes (especially the first one), are code with special bits.

Like "11110" for the first byte of a char with a value greater than 65 535.

So I implemented putchar (putwchar in fact), to handle these kind of char. But I handled with binary, because I don't understand how we can do with bitwise operation.

Nota bene : I use my own functions for atoi, memalloc etc. because we can't use the function present in the system.
My Implementation below (it's ugly, sorry, but it works):

```
#include <stddef.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define UNICODE "11110"
void bin(wchar_t n, int code)
{
    unsigned int    i;
    int             count;
    char        *byte1;
    char        *byte2;
    char        *byte3;
    char        *byte4;
    char        c[4];

    byte1 = ft_memalloc(8);
    byte2 = ft_memalloc(8);
    byte3 = ft_memalloc(8);
    byte4 = ft_memalloc(8);
    ft_strlcpy(byte1, &UNICODE[code], 9);
    ft_strlcpy(byte2, "10", 9);
    ft_strlcpy(byte3, "10", 9);
    ft_strlcpy(byte4, "10", 9);
    count = 0;
    if (code == 2)
    {
        i = 1 << 10;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            if (count < 5 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "1", 9);
            else if (count < 5 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 4 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 4 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "0", 9);
            i /= 2;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (code == 1)
    {
        i = 1 << 15;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            if (count < 4 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "1", 9);
            else if (count < 4 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 3 && count < 10 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 3 && count < 10 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 9 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte3, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 9 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte3, "0", 9);
            count++;
            i /= 2;
        }
    }
    if (code == 0)
    {
        i = 1 << 20;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            if (count < 3 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "1", 9);
            else if (count < 3 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte1, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 2 && count < 9 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 2 && count < 9 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte2, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 8 && count < 15  && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte3, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 8 && count < 15 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte3, "0", 9);
            else if (count > 14 && n & i)
                ft_strlcat(byte4, "1", 9);
            else if (count > 14 && !(n & i))
                ft_strlcat(byte4, "0", 9);
            count++;
            i /= 2;
        }
    }
    c[0] = ft_atoi_base(byte1, 2);
    c[1] = ft_atoi_base(byte2, 2);
    c[2] = ft_atoi_base(byte3, 2);
    c[3] = ft_atoi_base(byte4, 2);
    write(1, &c, 4 - code);

void    ft_putchar(int c)
{
    unsigned char ch;

    ch = (unsigned char)c;
    if ( c > 127)
    {
        if (c < 2048)
            bin(c, 2);
        else if (c < 65536)
            bin(c, 1);
        else
            bin(c, 0);
        return ;
    }
    write(1, &ch, 1);
}
}
```

My question is : how can I do to write these function in a less long manner? In other words : I know that there is a way to do the same thing with bitwise, but how it works? Do we do operation with some remarkable numbers? In fact, I don't like to not be able to think myself about something and write it without understand it and understand the logic of the code. I'm in this kind of case about the exercise resolved with bitwise operator and numbers that I don't understand why they are here.

Comment: You could learn bitwise operations?

Comment: Yup, I know a bit about bitwise operation, my question is why we use c[3] = 0x80 | (c & 0x3F); and not another number. Bitwise operation is not really the problem, the problem is tha mathematic logic behind the conversion or something like that. You can see that I use bitwise op in my function.

Comment: It isn't really mathematical logic, it is just how the standards committee decided to design UTF-8. Perhaps it is easier to understand if you write the numbers in binary? 0x80 is 10000000. 0x3F is 00111111. The 0x format is called hexadecimal.

Comment: @Batche you might want to read up on what [UTF-8 actually is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and how it works. `c & 0x3F` zeros all but the lower 6 bits of `c`, then `OR`ing with `0x80` sets the 8th bit to 1.  That is how the 2nd..4th bytes in a UTF-8 multi-byte sequence are formed.  There are a ton of questions on StackOverflow about working with UTF-8 in C/C++, I suggest you do some reading, plenty of examples of doing efficient Unicode-to-UTF8 conversions (yours is not very good). Or just get a good Unicode library, like libiconv, ICU, etc and let it do the hard work for you.

Comment: Yes thanks, I read about utf 8 and how it works, but for sure my code is not really effcient because I hardcoded how the bit are placed, and after I copied the bits of the char in the bytes 1 2 3 4... with a lot of repetitions. I tried to do it with my knowledge without copy/paste something from the web. But I'll try to figure out how we can pass from "000 1010 0010" to "11000010 10100010" for the ¢ for example. I cant use a library because we must code everything that we need. All the project are done with our library.